# What is the result of multiplying two disjunctive probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have seen this as a part of an equation numerous times -> $p(1-p)$ where $p$ is a probability that an event is going to happen. My question is what is the event that the result of this equation gives us.

Comment: You have an unfair coin with the $p = $ the chance of it coming up Heads.  What is the probability of getting exactly 1 Heads and 1 Tails on two tosses.  Alternatively, what is the chance of first getting a Heads and then getting a Tails.

Comment: @user2661923:  If understand your wording, the probability of your first event is twice the probability of the "alternative" event.

Comment: @hardmath true.  However, the point was merely to provide simple examples that each required creating the term $(p)(1-p)$.  Each of the problems require that specific multiplication as one works through the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The term $p(1-p)$ often appears in the context of [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with success probability $p$. Specifically, it is the probability that the first of two Bernoulli trials is successful and the second is not. It is also the probability that the second of two Bernoulli trials is successful and the first is not.

Note that by the above observations, the probability of exactly one success in two trials is $2p(1-p)$ since there are two ways we can choose the successful trial (either as the first or as the second). This is a special case of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: thank you kind sir